# Mouse scroll not working on Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, google-chrome

This is my first time posting a question, however I have searched everywhere and cannot find an answer. Recently the mouse scroll has stopped working on my Wordpress website in Google Chrome.  It works fine in Firefox however.  I have tried deactivating plugins, deleting and reinstalling but I just cannot seem to fix it. Is anyone able to assist or point me in the right direction?  My website is https://advicewrite.com.au
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yeah, scroll is fine for me too. I presume you have tried a cleansing reboot? How  about uninstalling and reinstalling your mouse driver?

Comment: Also is it not scrolling anywhere on the site at all for you? Are you logged in as admin to Wordpress when you are trying to scroll on the public site?

Comment: Thanks Guys. It is very strange as it doesn't work on a few computers in the office but the scroll works on a friends laptop.

Comment: Having the same issue... Scrolling used to work fine but stopped working recently. I see [more](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/YPIfzprM7Ao) [questions](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/BoarsOZwfYU) raised on this...

Answer (score 0):

scroll event is raised when the user scrolls to a different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set to scroll.

```
 <div style="width:300px; height:200px; border:1px solid black; overflow:scroll">
        Any thing long Code put  here
    </div>
    <br />
    <h3 style="display:none; color:red">Scroll event handled</h3>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('div').scroll(function () {
            $('h3').css('display', 'inline').fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

when you scroll in div then scroll fuction will get fire